# Accessing the host machine from within a Homestead guest VM with curl

Tags: php, prestashop, homestead

I'm trying to access api url which runs on my host machine from within a Homestead VM with curl. When I execute the code from within the guest VM it returns the error `Failed to connect to 10.0.2.15 port 8001: Connection refused`, `10.0.2.15` is the ip of the host inside the guest. I suspect the solution must be found in port forwading, I have tried port forwarding inside `Homestead.yml` but it did't resolve the issue.

This is the curl call.

```php
$defaultParams = array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => $this->apiKey.':',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array( 'Expect:' ),
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true
);

$url = 'http://10.0.2.15:8001/api/languages?display=full&ws_key=xxxxx';

$session = curl_init($url);

...
```

If I access the url on the host I get the expected result:

[image]